# best practice for graphql and amplify: how to get the counts of the hasMany associations?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying the blog example for AWS Amplify. Trying to figure out the way to get the counts of hasMany associations.

2 questions:

1. how to increase/decrease the comment count when create/delete a comment?
2. how to customized the generated query statement for the commentCound field

Here is the graphql.schema from my ampilfy project:

```
# This "input" configures a global authorization rule to enable public access to
# all models in this schema. Learn more about authorization rules here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules
input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public }
} # FOR TESTING ONLY!
#
#

type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany
  postCount: Int
}

type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @belongsTo
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
  commentCount: Int
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  post: Post @belongsTo
  content: String!
}
```